# How to drag and drop a marker in gantt chart

Tags: anychart

I am using marker on gantt chart (anychart) and I have to give drag and drop option to user. I am able to do that with periods but not with markers.

Answer (score 0):

Markers on Gantt chart are not interactive, they're just graphical elements. Therefore, they cannot be moved anywhere.